# mysql inner join query and index

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
"badges"

badge_id, merchant_id, badge_title, badge_desc, points_req

"badges_owned"

badge_id, customer_id, badge_points, badge_flag
```

and my query is :

```
SELECT badges.badge_id, badges.badge_title, badges.points_req, badges_owned.badge_flag, badges_owned.badge_points 
FROM badges 
INNER JOIN badges_owned ON badges.badge_id = badges_owned.badge_id 
WHERE badges_owned.customor_id = $user
```

My question is as follows, is this query the most efficient, but more so ...where would I place the indexes to make it optimal (just on the customor_id and badge_id?) or would I have to cover (never got this)?

Comment: The only real answer is that you have to test various indexes (covering as well as normal) by looking at the EXPLAIN PLAN, and review the index usage as you get more data (IE: approaching 1 million rows)

Answer (score 0):

You tend to use indexes for fields you are searching on or joining on.

Have a look at your select query and the ON fields and WHERE fields are the most likely candidates for indexes.

Keep in mind more indexes generally mean faster SELECTS, but also make for slower INSERTS.
There is a trade-off so don't go putting indexes of stuff just for the sake of it.

If you use EXPLAIN with your query it will show you the query plan and what indexes are being used. This will assist you on choosing where to place your indexes

Comment: so I would index badge_id for badges, but would I index badge_id and customer_id in the same btree (together) ...or could they be seperate, and it also depends on what is on the left most side in the where clause right?